# Create and assign a object property dynamically typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have an interface declared like this,

```
export interface OurHistory {
  ourHistory?: object;
  step1?:object;
  step2?:object;
}
```

Inside the class, I have

```
export class HistoryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  myHistory:OurHistory;

  let ourHistory = [];
  ourHistory = this.allHistory.fields['ourHistory'];
  this.myHistory.ourHistory = ourHistory[0];
}
```

I receive an error saying, Cannot set property 'ourHistory' of undefined

Comment: As myHistory variable is not initialized. By default it would be undefined.

Comment: either instantiate the myHistory variable from a class that implements the interface i.e myHistory = new Hisory() or use something like myHistory: OurHistory = {};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because on your second last line: `this.myHistory` is `undefined`. You are trying to access the property `ourHistory` of `undefined`, which the compiler does not like.

You need to instantiate the property, like mentioned in the comments to your question.

One way to do it, could do it like so:

```
export class HistoryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  myHistory: OurHistory;

  let ourHistory = [];
  ourHistory = this.allHistory.fields['ourHistory'];
  this.myHistory = {ourHistory: ourHistory[0]};
}
```

This way, we instantiate the property `myHistory` with a new object:

```
{
   ourHistory: someValue
}
```